# linux bash script error

Tags: bash

when I try to run this script

```
for ((i=1; i<=5; i++))
do
for ((j=1; j<=5; j++))
do
echo –n $i
done
echo " "
done
```

I get this error:

```
syntax error near unexpected token '(('

for ((j=1; j<=5; j++))"
```

Comment: missing shebang `#!/bin/bash`

Comment: Could you post the code before the snnipet here?

Comment: FYI: ***pure coding questions*** like these belong on Stack Overflow, not Ask Ubuntu.  ;)

Comment: Do you have a shebang (`#!/bin/bash`) as the first line of your script?

Comment: that not a dash `–n` should be `-n`

Comment: Or `for ((i=l=1;i<=5;l++<5?1:(i++,l=1))){ ((l==5))&&echo $i||echo -n $i;}`

Comment: This code can be run without shebang.

Comment: even if script will run with underlying shell and ultimately /bin/sh it may not be true for every exec* functions or platforms.

Comment: A more simple way, if possible, is to use: for i in {1..5}

Comment: This is odd. The error message appears to come from bash, but I'm not able to reproduce it. A `&nbsp;` after `for` is close, but gives ``bash: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `('`` without the double `((` on all versions I tried.  Can you please make sure to copy-paste the [complete, unabbreviated errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146/why-should-i-post-complete-errors-why-isnt-the-message-itself-enough), even though all the stuff around it seems irrelevant? Please include the prompt and command you wrote as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you're running this with an interpreter that is not bash. I've indented your code, but it worked just fine without indentation too.

```sh
$ cat test.bash
for ((i=1; i<=5; i++))
do
  for ((j=1; j<=5; j++))
  do
    echo –n $i
  done
  echo " "
done
```

```
$ /bin/sh test.bash
/tmp/test.bash: 1: Syntax error: Bad for loop variable
$ echo $BASH_VERSION
5.0.11(1)-release
$ bash test.bash
–n 1
–n 1
–n 1
–n 1
–n 1

–n 2
–n 2
…
```

As you can see, `echo -n` is not reliable. Change that line to `printf %s $i` to resolve that and your output will become:

```sh
11111 
22222 
33333 
44444 
55555
```

If you are invoking it with bash, perhaps your bash version is too old? You can use `for i in {1..5}` for something more compatible (but not valid POSIX) or you could use `for i in 1 2 3 4 5` for full POSIX compatibility. If you have GNU coreutils, you could do `for i in $(seq 5)` instead (see `man seq`).

To better approach your intended logic, you could also consider a `while` loop:

```sh
i=0
while [ $((++i)) -le 5 ]
do
  j=0
  while [ $((++j)) -le 5 ]
  do
    printf %s $i
  done
  echo " "
done
```

This initializes `i` to zero before a `while` loop, then increments it in the test condition when comparing it to five; the first loop's first iteration increments `i` to `1`, finds that it is indeed less than or equal (`-le`) to `5`, and therefore continues.

(I'm using a `$((…))` arithmetic expression and `++i` inside it since the more common `i++` would return the value of `i` *before* it is incremented while `++i` returns the value of `i` *after* it is incremented.)